# Underscore.js template compilation

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, frontend, underscore.js-templating

Basically what I'm trying to do is to compile template with some data usin underscore js. My code follows:

```
var temp = "<div> Hello <%=names%> </div>";
var html = _.template(temp, {names:'world'};
```

I'm expecting for my variable html to be

```
<div> Hello world </div>
```

but for some reason variable names is undefined while compilation and template never compiles.

This is the most basic thing with underscore js and according to [documentation](http://underscorejs.org/#template) and numerous examples on web it should work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [_.template function](http://underscorejs.org/#template) has changed a little bit, assuming you're on the latest version, it now produces a function instead of the compiled HTML which you have to call with the data you want to be displayed.

```
var temp = "<div> Hello <%= names %> </div>";
var html = _.template(temp);
console.log(html({names:'world'}));

"<div> Hello world </div>"
```

Comment: You just saved my life...

Comment: No problems, happy hacking! :)